# Jquery Datepicker in french

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker

In my multilingual site (In 7 languages) i want to use Date picker in format ('dd-M-yy). I have a validation for english and it works perfectly but when i translate the Datepicker in french it cause problem and shows invalide date for few months (Specially in gen (Jan) and des (Dec)). Our DB have the data in english so that i want all validation should be in english but users seen the their local language.

I used below code to translate datepicker:

```
datepicker.regional.ca = {
    closeText: "Tanca",
    prevText: "Anterior",
    nextText: "Seg\u00fcent",
    currentText: "Avui",
    monthNames: [ "gener","febrer","mar\u00e7","abril","maig","juny","juliol","agost","setembre","octubre","novembre","desembre" ],
    monthNamesShort: [ "gen","feb","mar\u00e7","abr","maig","juny","jul","ag","set","oct","nov","des" ],
    dayNames: [ "diumenge","dilluns","dimarts","dimecres","dijous","divendres","dissabte" ],
    dayNamesShort: [ "dg","dl","dt","dc","dj","dv","ds" ],
    dayNamesMin: [ "dg","dl","dt","dc","dj","dv","ds" ],
    weekHeader: "Set",
    dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy",
    firstDay: 1,
    isRTL: false,
    showMonthAfterYear: false,
    yearSuffix: "" };
datepicker.setDefaults( datepicker.regional.ca );

return datepicker.regional.ca;
```

and below code to validate the Date:

```
monthName=['Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May','Jun','Jul','Aug','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dec'];
dateselected = "10-gen-2016";
var selectedDateTime = new Date(dateselected);
        alert(selectedDateTime);
        var selectedDateInEnglish =  selectedDateTime.getDate()+'-'+monthName[selectedDateTime.getMonth()]+'-'+selectedDateTime.getFullYear();
        alert(selectedDateInEnglish);
        var filter = /^([012]?\d|3[01])-([Jj][Aa][Nn]|[Ff][Ee][bB]|[Mm][Aa][Rr]|[Aa][Pp][Rr]|[Mm][Aa][Yy]|[Jj][Uu][Nn]|[Jj][Uu][Ll]|[aA][Uu][gG]|[Ss][eE][pP]|[oO][Cc][Tt]|[Nn][oO][Vv]|[Dd][Ee][Cc])-(19|20)\d\d$/
        return filter.test(selectedDateInEnglish);
```

But when i converted the date with new object it shows Invalid date and i am not able to get the selected month in english.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: And how do you solve the validation on the serverside, cause you do of course validate this on the server. Clientside validation isn't really needed at all, but if you want to make it easier for the client to type the correct format, you'd have to also change the validation to work with the french names for months etc.

Comment: Thanks adeneo for your response. This site is only visible for selected users so did not have server side validation. Anyhow we pass the value to server in english because data is in english that's why i want to validate in english

Comment: Here's what I would do. I'd set up an `altField` with a `altFormat` in english. The datepicker supports this, and the alternate field would always be set to english, and you'd validate and submit that field. Getting the altField is easy, you'd just call `$(element).datepicker( "option", "altField" )` to get the field for validation. It's either that, or using two different validations for each language.

Comment: Thanks adeneo. It solve my problem in some manners but i have a more than 50 fields in site so that i want to add altField dynamically and fill the altFormat value in it. Could you please help me to solve this problem. i used $(".fromReport").datepicker({
dateFormat: 'dd-M-yy', altFormat: "dd-mm-yy", altField: '#'+this.name+'_hidden', onClose: function(selectedDate) {
   var inputHiddenField = '<input type="hidden" name="'+this.name+'_hidden" id="'+this.name+'_hidden" value="" />';
   $(this).parent('form').append(inputHiddenField);